# How to avoid receiving data from old redux requests?

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-toolkit

I'm using reactjs with redux toolkit and axios.

My code:

```
export const Dashboard2 = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const isAuth = Boolean(window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
    const {user, transactions} = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchAuthMe());
        dispatch(fetchAuthGetTransactions());
    }, []);

    const isLoaded = Boolean(user.status === 'loaded' && transactions.status === 'loaded');

    if (!isAuth) {
        return  <Navigate to="/auth"/>;
    }

    if (isLoaded) {
        if (!user.data.success){
            dispatch(logout);
            console.log("Удаляю токен Dashboard2")
            return window.localStorage.removeItem("token");
        }
        return (
            <div className="">
                <div className="flex h-screen antialiased text-gray-900 bg-gray-100 dark:bg-dark dark:text-light">
                    <Aside/>
                    <TopBar user={user.data} transactions={transactions.data}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Store.js

```
import {applyMiddleware, configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {authReducer} from "./slices/auth";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from '@redux-devtools/extension';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        auth: authReducer
    },

}, {}, composeWithDevTools(middleware));

export default store;
```

slices/auth.js

```
import {createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "../../axios";


export const fetchAuth = createAsyncThunk('auth/fetchAuth', async (params) => {
    const {data} = await axios.post('/api/auth', params);
    return data;
});

export const fetchAuthMe = createAsyncThunk('auth/fetchAuthMe', async () => {
    const {data} = await axios.get('/api/me');
    return data;
});

export const fetchAuthRegister = createAsyncThunk('auth/fetchAuthRegister', async (params) => {
    const {data} = await axios.post('/api/register', params);
    return data;
});

export const fetchAuthReset = createAsyncThunk('auth/fetchAuthReset', async (params) => {
    const {data} = await axios.post('/api/reset', params);
    return data;
});

export const fetchAuthChangePassword = createAsyncThunk('auth/fetchAuthChangePassword', async (params) => {

    const {data} = await axios.patch('/api/reset', params);
    return data;
});

export const fetchAuthGetTransactions = createAsyncThunk('auth/fetchAuthGetTransactions', async () => {
    const {data} = await axios.get('/api/getTransactions');
    return data;
});


const initialState = {
    user: {
        data: '',
        status: 'loading',
    },
    transactions: {
        data: '',
        status: 'loading',
    }
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        logout: (state) => {
            state.data = null;
            state.user.data = null;
            state.transactions.data = null;
        }
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [fetchAuth.pending]: (state) => {
            state.status = 'loading';
            state.data = null;
        },
        [fetchAuth.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'loaded';
            state.data = action.payload;
        },
        [fetchAuth.rejected]: (state) => {
            state.status = 'loaded';
            state.data = null;
        },
        [fetchAuthReset.pending]: (state) => {
            state.status = 'loading';
            state.data = null;
        },
        [fetchAuthReset.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'loaded';
            state.data = action.payload;
        },
        [fetchAuthReset.rejected]: (state) => {
            state.status = 'loaded';
            state.data = null;
        },
        [fetchAuthChangePassword.pending]: (state) => {
            state.status = 'loading';
            state.data = null;
        },
        [fetchAuthChangePassword.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'loaded';
            state.data = action.payload;
        },
        [fetchAuthChangePassword.rejected]: (state) => {
            state.status = 'loaded';
            state.data = null;
        },
        [fetchAuthMe.pending]: (state) => {
            state.user.status = 'loading';
            state.user.data = null;
        },
        [fetchAuthMe.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.user.status = 'loaded';
            state.user.data = action.payload;
        },
        [fetchAuthMe.rejected]: (state) => {
            state.user.status = 'error';
            state.user.data = null;
        },
        [fetchAuthRegister.pending]: (state) => {
            state.status = 'loading';
            state.data = null;
        },
        [fetchAuthRegister.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'loaded';
            state.data = action.payload;
        },
        [fetchAuthRegister.rejected]: (state) => {
            state.status = 'error';
            state.data = null;
        },
        [fetchAuthGetTransactions.pending]: (state) => {
            state.transactions.status = 'loading';
            state.transactions.data = null;
        },
        [fetchAuthGetTransactions.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.transactions.status = 'loaded';
            state.transactions.data = action.payload;
        },
        [fetchAuthGetTransactions.rejected]: (state) => {
            state.transactions.status = 'error';
            state.transactions.data = null;
        },
    }
});


// export const selectIsAuth = Boolean(window.localStorage.getItem('token'))
export const authReducer = authSlice.reducer;

export const {logout} = authSlice.actions
```

Tell me what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Now I checked when entering the dashboard. If a request for user information returns that the user is not authorized. Then the user is redirected to the authorization page. When I test this, emulating an invalid token, everything works, but after logging into the account, the user is immediately thrown out because

```
const {user, transactions} = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
```

first returns the result of old queries.